# How to animate the frame of an layer with CABasicAnimation?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I guess I have to convert the CGRect into an object to pass it to fromValue?

This is how I try it, but it doesn't work:

```
CABasicAnimation *frameAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"frame"];
frameAnimation.duration = 2.5;
frameAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
frameAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:myLayer.frame];
frameAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:theNewFrameRect];
[myLayer addAnimation:frameAnimation forKey:@"MLC"];
```

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I guess you need to change your last line to make it work:

```
[myLayer addAnimation:frameAnimation forKey:@"frame"];
```

You may also set an action to the layer to make all frame changes animated with your animation:

```
CABasicAnimation *frameAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
frameAnimation.duration = 2.5;
frameAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

myLayer.actions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:frameAnimation, @"frame", nil];
```

In CALayer's `actionForKey:` method reference you can find how layer looks up for the actions to animated its properties.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. I have found that CALayer can't animate the frame property directly. The documentation says that in a gray box. Haven't seen it for some reason.

Comment: The last line is fine as it is - the key you specify in addAnimation can be an arbitrary NSString. I think the actual answer is beryllium's below

Comment: `[myLayer addAnimation:frameAnimation forKey:@"frame"];` `frame` is just a name for the animation and have nothing to do with the actual property being animated...

Comment: I think you can animate in the context of this QA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827973/core-animation-progress-callback?lq=1

Answer (score 103):

The frame property of a CALayer is a derived property, dependent on the position, anchorPoint, bounds and transform of the layer. Instead of animating the frame, you should instead animate the position or bounds, depending on what effect you are trying to accomplish.

To move a layer, you can animate the `position`:

```
-(void)moveLayer:(CALayer*)layer to:(CGPoint)point
{
    // Prepare the animation from the current position to the new position
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    animation.fromValue = [layer valueForKey:@"position"];

    // NSValue/+valueWithPoint:(NSPoint)point is available on Mac OS X
    // NSValue/+valueWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point is available on iOS
    // comment/uncomment the corresponding lines depending on which platform you're targeting

    // Mac OS X
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithPoint:NSPointFromCGPoint(point)];
    // iOS
    //animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];

    // Update the layer's position so that the layer doesn't snap back when the animation completes.
    layer.position = point;

    // Add the animation, overriding the implicit animation.
    [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
}
```

To resize a layer, you would animate the `bounds` parameter:

```
-(void)resizeLayer:(CALayer*)layer to:(CGSize)size
{
    // Prepare the animation from the old size to the new size
    CGRect oldBounds = layer.bounds;
    CGRect newBounds = oldBounds;
    newBounds.size = size;
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];

    // NSValue/+valueWithRect:(NSRect)rect is available on Mac OS X
    // NSValue/+valueWithCGRect:(CGRect)rect is available on iOS
    // comment/uncomment the corresponding lines depending on which platform you're targeting

    // Mac OS X
    animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithRect:NSRectFromCGRect(oldBounds)];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithRect:NSRectFromCGRect(newBounds)];
    // iOS
    //animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:oldBounds];
    //animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:newBounds];

    // Update the layer's bounds so the layer doesn't snap back when the animation completes.
    layer.bounds = newBounds;

    // Add the animation, overriding the implicit animation.
    [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"bounds"];
}
```

You can combine these animations using a CAAnimationGroup if you need to move and resize a layer at the same time.

Comment: This answer (the Technical Q&A) is outdated.

Comment: The problem of putting only links is that they die and the answer becomes useless. SO should deduct points for every link posted. SMH.

Comment: Is it ok to animate the transform property to achieve movement and resize animation with a single animation?

Answer (score 7):

we can change the properties of "bounds" and "position" to animate it, such as

```
-(void)handleTap2:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    UIImageView *vw = (UIImageView *)[recognizer view];

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(vw.frame.size.width/2+vw.frame.origin.x, vw.frame.size.height/2+vw.frame.origin.y); 
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(160, 240);

    CGRect startBounds = vw.bounds; 
    CGRect stopBounds = self.view.bounds;

    layer = [CALayer layer]; 
    layer.frame = self.view.frame; 
    layer.contents = (id)[vw.image CGImage];

    [self.view.window.layer addSublayer:layer];

    CABasicAnimation * baseAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];

    baseAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]; 
    baseAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:startPoint] ; 
    baseAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPoint] ;

    CABasicAnimation * boundsAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];

    boundsAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]; 
    boundsAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:startBounds] ; boundsAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:stopBounds] ;

    CAAnimationGroup * group =[CAAnimationGroup animation]; 
    group.removedOnCompletion=NO; group.fillMode=kCAFillModeForwards; 
    group.animations =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:baseAnimation, boundsAnimation, nil];    
    group.duration = 0.7;

    [layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"frame"]; 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The question is antique, but I will answer it anyway.

Frame property is not animatable. You have to animate other properties. Also you have to disable implicit animations.

```
    let updatedBounds = ...
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
    animation.duration = 0.5
    //it's better to start animation from presentation layer in case there is already animation going on
    animation.fromValue = customLayer.presentation()?.bounds
    animation.toValue = updatedBounds
    customLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)

    //disable implicit animation for thoose properties
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
    //update properties so they will be updated at the end of animation
    customLayer.bounds = updatedBounds
    customLayer.position = originalRect.origin
    customLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: THIS SAVED ME! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Extension in swift 4

```
import UIKit

extension CALayer {
    func moveTo(point: CGPoint, animated: Bool) {
        if animated {
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
            animation.fromValue = value(forKey: "position")
            animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: point)
            animation.fillMode = .forwards
            self.position = point
            add(animation, forKey: "position")
        } else {
            self.position = point
        }
    }

    func resize(to size: CGSize, animated: Bool) {
        let oldBounds = bounds
        var newBounds = oldBounds
        newBounds.size = size

        if animated {
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
            animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgRect: oldBounds)
            animation.toValue = NSValue(cgRect: newBounds)
            animation.fillMode = .forwards
            self.bounds = newBounds
            add(animation, forKey: "bounds")
        } else {
            self.bounds = newBounds
        }
    }

    func resizeAndMove(frame: CGRect, animated: Bool, duration: TimeInterval = 0) {
        if animated {
            let positionAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
            positionAnimation.fromValue = value(forKey: "position")
            positionAnimation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY))

            let oldBounds = bounds
            var newBounds = oldBounds
            newBounds.size = frame.size

            let boundsAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
            boundsAnimation.fromValue = NSValue(cgRect: oldBounds)
            boundsAnimation.toValue = NSValue(cgRect: newBounds)

            let groupAnimation = CAAnimationGroup()
            groupAnimation.animations = [positionAnimation, boundsAnimation]
            groupAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
            groupAnimation.duration = duration
            groupAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
            self.frame = frame
            add(groupAnimation, forKey: "frame")

        } else {
            self.frame = frame
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May Christ the Lord himself come and bless your soul

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple, fully working, example which may help someone.

Just call `.slideUp()` on the class and it will slide up.

```
class Slidey: YourViewClass {

    func slideUp() {

        print("\n\n SLIDE")

        let FF = layer.position
        var TT = FF
        TT.y -= 100
        print(FF)
        print(TT)

        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock{ [weak self] in

            print("DONE")
        }

        let a = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")

        a.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)

        a.isCumulative = false
        a.autoreverses = false
        a.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
        a.repeatCount = 0
        a.fromValue = FF
        a.toValue = TT
        a.duration = 0.70
        layer.add(a, forKey: nil)

        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```