# CABasicAnimation move frame left by 300px

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, animation, core-animation

I need help with CABasicAnimation. I am trying to move a NSView left by 300 pixels. I found this SO thread: [How to animate the frame of an layer with CABasicAnimation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892888/how-to-animate-the-frame-of-an-layer-with-cabasicanimation)

Turns out animating the frame is not possible and one of the answer points to a link to QA on Apple's website but it takes me a to a generic page:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1620/_index.html

So, how can I do something as simple as translation of my NSView/CALyer?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSView has a protocol called NSAnimatablePropertyContainer which allows you to create basic animations for views:

> The NSAnimatablePropertyContainer protocol defines a way to add
>   animation to an existing class with a minimum of API impact ...
>   Sending of key-value-coding compliant "set" messages to the proxy will
>   trigger animation for automatically animated properties of its target
>   object.

The NSAnimatablePropertyContainer protocol can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSAnimatablePropertyContainer_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html)

I recently used this technique to change the origin of a frame:

```
-(void)setOrigin:(NSPoint)aPoint {
    [[self animator] setFrameOrigin:aPoint];
}
```

Instead of calling the [view setFrameOrigin:], I created another method called setOrigin: which then applies the setFrameOrigin: call to the view's animator.

If you need to change the duration of the animation, you can do so like this (similar to CATransactions):

```
-(void)setOrigin:(NSPoint)aPoint {
    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setCompletionHandler:^{
        ...Completion Callback Code goes here...
    }];
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:1.0];
    [[self animator] setFrameOrigin:aPoint];
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
}
```

The NSAnimationContext is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSAnimationContext_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: The reason why I am using CABasicAnimation is because I need a callback for when the animation ends

Comment: In the NSAnimationContext documentation, you can check the – setCompletionHandler: method which lets you set a callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate `center` property instead. Eg:

```
//assuming view is your NSView
CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(view.center.x - 300, view.center.y);
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
//setup your animation eg. duration/other options
animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:v.center];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:newCenter];
[view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"key"];
```

Comment: thanks for the input. Will try this out. Just curious, why are we not passing in key path when initializing? "animationWithKeyPath:"

Comment: Well we don't need it here, it's useful mostly for transformations, when we don't want to construct fullblown CATransform3D but rather say "animate `translation.x` from value 0 to value 10".

Comment: This is incorrect. Layer-backed NSView owns its layer, you should consider it an implementation detail. You should not touch backing layer or add animations directly to it. NSAnimatablePropertyContainer is a way to go.