# How to use an additive animation on AVPlayerLayer bounds?

Tags: objective-c, macos, animation, avfoundation, core-animation

I'm trying to do an additive animation on a AVPlayerLayer's bounds. By simply setting additive to YES, it breaks the animation. I need to do it additive so that the width and height can be animated with different animation parameters. Animating the key paths bounds.size.width and bounds.size.height do not work either.

I can animate other CALayer classes fine with the below code, so I'm starting to wonder if AVPlayerLayer has a bug.

Here is the code:

```
AVPlayerLayer *vl; 

// ...


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    NSURL *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"vid" withExtension:@"mp4"]];
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL: path];
    vl = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
    vl.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize;
//     vl = [CALayer layer]; // a normal calayer animates properly

    vl.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor].CGColor;
    vl.frame = CGRectMake(200,100,150,100);
    [_window.contentView.layer addSublayer:vl];
}

- (IBAction)animate:(id)sender {
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
    animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithRect:CGRectMake(0,0,0, 0)];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithRect:CGRectMake(0,0,240, 60)];
    animation.duration = 4;
    animation.additive = YES;

    [vl addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

The red area should be the video playing.

You can check out the sample project I created here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jxuh69wiqdwnuc6/PlayerLayer%20size%20Animation.zip?dl=1

Answer (score 0):

The frame property of a `CALayer` is a derived property, dependent on the position, anchorPoint, bounds and transform of the layer. Instead of animating the frame, you should instead animate the `position` or `bounds`, depending on what effect you are trying to accomplish.

You may first take a look at this:

[Q:  When I try to animate the frame of a CALayer nothing happens. Why?](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/qa/qa1620/_index.html)

This can also help：
[How to animate the frame of an layer with CABasicAnimation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892888/how-to-animate-the-frame-of-an-layer-with-cabasicanimation/5340339)

And those code may be helpul to you:

```
NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"yourFilePath"];
AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:fileUrl];

CALayer *superlayer = self.view.layer;
AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
[superlayer addSublayer:playerLayer];

[player play];

playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize;
playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(10, 200, 320, 200);
playerLayer.position = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2);

CGRect startBounds = CGRectMake(10, 200, 200, 150);
CGRect endBounds = CGRectMake(10, 200, 320, 200);

CABasicAnimation * sizeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];

sizeAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithRect:startBounds] ;
sizeAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithRect:endBounds] ;
sizeAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
sizeAnimation.duration = 4;

[playerLayer addAnimation:sizeAnimation forKey:@"bounds"];
```

Comment: The code in the question _is_ animating bounds, not frame. The code example in the original question works for normal CALayers, so it seems to be a quirk specific to AVPlayerLayers

Comment: The code example in the original question is animating bounds also! Because you can't animate the frame of a CALayer !