# Animating View jumps to final position instead of slow movement

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I am working on animating my view which contains an ImageView and a Label.
Please see figure 1. I am trying to animate upperView when scrolling on below tableView is done. And the final result should look like Figure 2. where the imageView's height and width is reduced and is at the left corner with minimum height and label in front of the imageView. Animation is working fine, the imageView goes from Original position to final position smoothly and so does the Label. But the upperView doesn't works as per the animation.

I tried it with upperViews Height Constraint and by its frame.

1. If I change it with its height Constraint it goes to its final position very quickly.
2. And if I give height using upperView.frame.size.height then the view goes up but the table view remains on their places.

Here is what I have tried

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0
        {
         UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations:
                    {
                        self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 0.0, width: 30, height: 40)

                    }, completion: { finished in
                        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction,animations: {

                            self.selectedProgramNameLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.selectedProgramNameLabel.center.x, y: self.imageView.center.y)

                            }, completion: { finished in
                                UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 2.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {

                              self.upperViewHeightConstraint.constant = 50

                                    }, completion: { finished in

                                })
                        })
                })
        }
        else if scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0
        {
          UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations:
                {
                    self.selectedProgramNameLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.selectedProgramNameLabel.center.x, y: self.imageView.center.y + self.imageView.frame.height - 45)


                }, completion: { finished in
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction,animations: {

                        self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.upperView.frame.origin.x, y: self.upperView.frame.origin.y, width: 100.0, height: 134)


                        }, completion: { finished in
                            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {


                                }, completion: { finished in


                            })
                    })
            })

       }
```

TIA.

Figure 1.
  [image]
Figure 2.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

While animating any layout constraints, it is must to use `layoutIfNeeded` in animation block if you want desired animation effect. So just add this one in animation block.

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
self.upperViewHeightConstraint.constant = 50
```

Also use any flag to check whether views have been animated, otherwise your animation block will executed number of times.

Comment: I have tried self.view.layoutIfNeeded() before, but still it acts the same way. Jumps to the final position.

Comment: your animation blocks are being executed multiple times, make them animate once.

Comment: Yes I made it execute once, But still it doesn't animates. It Jumps :(

Comment: you are saying that upper view is not animating right?

Comment: Yes buddy. It directly jumps to i.e Goes to height 50

Comment: try it , 
self.upperViewHeightConstraint.constant = 50;
self.upperView.layoutIfNeeded()
means layout method after constant change

Comment: If I add self.upperView.layoutIfNeeded() then Image and Label disappears

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:  UIViewAnimationOptions.beginFromCurrentState, CABasicAnimation.
[How to animate the frame of an layer with CABasicAnimation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892888/how-to-animate-the-frame-of-an-layer-with-cabasicanimation)

It's not what are you looking for but I hope that can help you.

[image]

```
var cntTopViewT: NSLayoutConstraint!
var cntTopViewH: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    let topView = UIView()
    topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.addSubview(topView)

    let topViewBackgroundImageView = UIImageView()
    topViewBackgroundImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    topView.addSubview(topViewBackgroundImageView)

    let bottomView = UIView()
    bottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.insertSubview(bottomView, at: 0)

    let v = UIView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bottomView.addSubview(v)


    let views: [String: Any] = ["view": view,
                                "scrollView": scrollView,
                                "topView": topView,
                                "topViewBackgroundImageView": topViewBackgroundImageView,
                                "bottomView": bottomView,
                                "v": v]
    var cnts: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

    cnts += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[scrollView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    cnts += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[scrollView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

    cnts += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[topView(scrollView)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    cnts += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[scrollView]-0@1-[topView]", options: [.alignAllCenterX], metrics: nil, views: views)
    cntTopViewT = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    cntTopViewH = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    cnts += [cntTopViewT, cntTopViewH]

    cnts += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[topViewBackgroundImageView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    cnts += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[topViewBackgroundImageView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

    cnts += [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bottomView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.9, constant: 0)]
    cnts += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[scrollView]-0@1-[bottomView]|", options: [.alignAllCenterX], metrics: nil, views: views)
    cnts += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[bottomView(999)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

    cnts += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v(50)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    cnts += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v(50)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(cnts)

    topView.backgroundColor = .red
    bottomView.backgroundColor = .green
    v.backgroundColor = .blue
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let minH = (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0) + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
    let maxH = view.frame.height * 0.35

    cntTopViewT.constant = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    cntTopViewH.constant = max(-scrollView.contentOffset.y, minH)
    scrollView.contentInset.top = maxH
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets.top = (cntTopViewH.constant - minH) + (minH * ((cntTopViewH.constant - minH) / (maxH - minH))) + 5

    //let kTransform = min(max(cntTopViewH.constant / maxH + 0.1, 0.5), 1)
    //topViewFioLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(a: kTransform, b: 0, c: 0, d: kTransform, tx: 0, ty: 0)
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer but I have tried this before. And this works only if there is enough data on table view to scroll, else my imageView and label are stuck in between which looks very ugly. So had to use UIAnimation so that it moves to its destination even if data on table is less. But the upperView Height constraint is not moving when I animate, it moves like a bullet which is not acceptable.